# How to restore the data of the cancelled data expiration ttl in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: ttl, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I set an data expiration policy using `ttl` in Apache IoTDB and then cancelled this setting. Then the data that is set to expire when the expiration policy is valid cannot be queried, but it should not have been deleted. I want to know is there any way to restore these data in IoTDB?

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expired data set by `ttl` in Apache IoTDB will be cleared every minute. If your data disappears after `ttl` cancellation, then it should have been deleted and cannot be restored. Check to see if there is backup data to restore them.